# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'

Tags: python, machine-learning, adaboost, ensemble-learning, boosting

Hi I want to use a simple [AdaBoostClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.AdaBoostClassifier.html) on the mushroom dataset which lools smth. like:

```
target  cap-shape  cap-surface  cap-color  bruises  odor  \
3059       0          2            3          2        1     5   
1953       0          5            0          3        1     5   
1246       0          2            2          3        0     5   
5373       1          5            2          8        1     2   
413        0          5            3          9        1     3
```

...

using:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import pandas as pd

dataset = pd.read_csv('data\mushroom.csv',header=None)
dataset = dataset.sample(frac=1)
dataset.columns = ['target','cap-shape','cap-surface','cap-color','bruises','odor','gill-attachment','gill-spacing',
             'gill-size','gill-color','stalk-shape','stalk-root','stalk-surface-above-ring','stalk-surface-below-ring','stalk-color-above-ring',
             'stalk-color-below-ring','veil-type','veil-color','ring-number','ring-type','spore-print-color','population',
             'habitat']

for label in dataset.columns:
    dataset[label] = LabelEncoder().fit(dataset[label]).transform(dataset[label])


X = dataset.drop(['target'],axis=1)
Y = dataset['target']


AdaBoost = AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator='DecisionTreeClassifier',n_estimators=400,learning_rate=0.01,algorithm='SAMME')

AdaBoost.fit(X,Y)

prediction = AdaBoost.score(Y)

print(prediction)
```

but this returns me:

> ---> 15 AdaBoost.fit(X,Y)
>
> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'

Comment: That error simply means that the `AdaBoost` object is a `str`, and thus doing `AdaBoost.fit` is analogous to doing `"string".fit`. Something wrong is happening creating the `AdaBoost` object.

Comment: Try printing `AdaBoost`. What does it look like?

Comment: AdaBoostClassifier(algorithm='SAMME', base_estimator='DecisionTreeClassifier',
          learning_rate=0.01, n_estimators=400, random_state=None)

Comment: Nothing special. If I change the name from AdaBoost to A, the same error occurs. The algorithm is correctly instantiated but there must be something else wrong

Comment: @ResetACK I have found the issue. As base_estimator I have set 'DecisionTreeClassifier'. THIS is a sting and has no fit() method. The AdaBoost IS NOT a string

Comment: A good practice to get into is to debug your scripts by using `python -i <script>`. This launches the script in the interpreter, which would allow you to do `dir(AdaBoost)`, giving you the available attributes of the object (or run other commands to manipulate the data without having to edit, save, and then run the script over and over)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. As base_estimator I have set 'DecisionTreeClassifier'. THIS is a sting and has no fit() method. The AdaBoost IS NOT a string.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import AdaBoostClassifier
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

for label in dataset.columns:
    dataset[label] = LabelEncoder().fit(dataset[label]).transform(dataset[label])

X = dataset.drop(['target'],axis=1)
Y = dataset['target']


AdaBoost = AdaBoostClassifier(n_estimators=400,learning_rate=0.01,algorithm='SAMME')

AdaBoost.fit(X,Y)

prediction = AdaBoost.score(X,Y)

print(prediction)
```

> 0.9182668636139832

Comment: Removing the parameter is the solution? I'm doing a gridsearch on base estimator and listing DecisionTreeClassifier and RandomForestClassifier as my models. But it's failing because of this issue. How can I evaluate different models without using this parameter?

Answer (score 2):

In reference to my comment in 2Obe's answer above, I found the correct way to specify the parameter -

```
AdaBoostClassifier(base_estimator=DecisionTreeClassifier(),n_estimators=400,learning_rate=0.01,algorithm='SAMME')
```

It should be a constructor rather than a string